# JavaFX TableView click sorters not working?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Why is my TableColumn.setSortable() showing the sort graphic on the table header when I double-click on it, but it is not actually doing any sort at all? I would imagine it naturally knows how to sort Numbers? Do I have to set an explicit comparator even for types that have a natural sort behavior?

```
public class PenaltyDashboardManager { 

    private final TableView<Penalty> penaltyTable = new TableView<Penalty>();

    /* ... */

    private void initializeTable() { 

        penaltyTable.setItems(Penalty.getPenaltyManager().getPenalties());
        penaltyTable.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<Penalty,Number> penaltyId = new TableColumn<>("ID");
        penaltyId.setCellValueFactory(c -> c.getValue().getPenaltyIdProperty());
        penaltyId.setEditable(true);
        penaltyId.setSortable(true);    
        /* ... */

        penaltyTable.getColumns.add(penaltyId);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

Very odd. I tried to create a simple example to demonstate the sorting not working. But this simple column of integers is sorting just fine :/

```
public final  class TableSortTest extends Application {

    private static final ObservableList<NumericCombo> values = FXCollections.observableList(
            IntStream.range(1, 100).mapToObj(i -> new NumericCombo()).collect(Collectors.toList()));

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Collections.shuffle(values);

        TableView<NumericCombo> tableView = new TableView<>();
        tableView.setItems(values);

        TableColumn<NumericCombo,Number> combo1 = new TableColumn<>("COMBO 1");
        combo1.setCellValueFactory(c -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(c.getValue().combo1));

        TableColumn<NumericCombo,Number> combo2 = new TableColumn<>("COMBO 2");
        combo2.setCellValueFactory(c -> c.getValue().combo2);

        TableColumn<NumericCombo,Number> combo3 = new TableColumn<>("COMBO 3");
        combo3.setCellValueFactory(c -> c.getValue().combo3);

        tableView.getColumns().addAll(combo1,combo2,combo3);

        Group root = new Group(tableView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);   

        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private static final class NumericCombo { 
        private static final Random rand = new Random();

        private final int combo1;
        private final IntegerProperty combo2;
        private final IntegerProperty combo3;

        private NumericCombo() {
            combo1 = rand.nextInt((10000 - 0) + 1);
            combo2 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(rand.nextInt((10000 - 0) + 1));
            combo3 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(rand.nextInt((10000 - 0) + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that when you click on column header for `ID`, it doesn't sort?

Comment: Positive. Is it possible being on JRE1.0.0_25 could be an issue?

Comment: It should work for natural sorting data types

Comment: Considering that as `JRE 1.8.0_25`. I can confirm that sorting on `TableColumn< T, Number >` works perfectly. Can you please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) supporting the behaviour posting in your question?

Comment: Okay I'll compose something after lunch that replicates the issue.

Comment: Works fine for me too. Note you don't actually need `setSortable(true)` as that is the default.

Comment: Very, very odd. I created a simple table with one column with Integers, and it sorted just fine. Let me see if I can replicate this issue and get it to break like I want it to.

Comment: I made some more complicated samples and I'm still getting the correct sort order. I don't know how I can create an MCVE that captures this problem, and I can't just put the code in question on SO.  I suppose it wouldn't make a different if I was embedding it in Swing via JFXPanel? Because that is the only difference I can find.

Comment: I tested that too, and that's not it.

Comment: Have been there, but can't remember what made me hit the head on table at the end. What exactly are you seeing when clicking the header? Nothing at all or weird sort order? The latter might be an indication of mixed concrete number types (not probable, catching at straws ;-) - Number is not comparable, only its subclasses are. Unrelated: for best results you would wrap the data into a SortedList - otherwise, unsorting doesn't work.

Comment: Found the issue! Answer is below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue! I was using my own implementation of ObservableList, called ObservableImmutableList. It wraps the ObservableList interface around a Guava ImmutableList. Since the ImmutableList is not modifiable, it cannot be sorted... even in a TableView.

This transitions to another issue I'm struggling to figure out. How do I sort my `ObservableImmutableList`? [So I posted another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29630944/how-do-i-make-my-immutablelist-sortable-in-its-observablelist-wrapper).