# How do I make my ImmutableList sortable in its ObservableList wrapper?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, guava

I have my own implementation of `ObservableList` called `ObservableImmutableList`. It wraps a Guava `ImmutableList` with the `ObservableList` interface so I can fully utilize `ImmutableList` easily with JavaFX. There is nothing mutable about it except it allows another `ImmutableList` to be swapped in as the backing list using the `set()` method (and notify all listeners/bindings of the change).

However, [one problem I ran into is the `ObservableImmutableList` cannot be sorted.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29610358/javafx-tableview-click-sorters-not-working?noredirect=1#comment47391866_29610358) I cannot extend or implement `SortedList`, so how do I implement it into this class?

I tried to create a method `asSorted`() which returns the `ObservableImmutableList` wrapped in a `SortedList`. But it also would not work. Is there some kind of simple abstract layer I can use to keep the list Immutable but allow the values to be resorted in the abstracted layer?

```
public final class ObservableImmutableList<T> implements ObservableList<T> {
    private volatile ImmutableList<T> backingList;
    private final LazyProperty<SortedList<T>> sortedList = LazyProperty.forSupplier(() -> new SortedList<>(this));
    private final CopyOnWriteArrayList<ListChangeListener<? super T>> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    private final CopyOnWriteArrayList<InvalidationListener> invalidationListeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    private final ObjectProperty<ObservableList<T>> property;

    private ObservableImmutableList(ImmutableList<T> immutableList) {
        this.backingList = immutableList;
        this.property = new SimpleObjectProperty<ObservableList<T>>(this);
    }

    public static <T> ObservableImmutableList<T> of(ImmutableList<T> immutableList) {
        return new ObservableImmutableList<T>(immutableList);
    }
    public SortedList<T> asSorted() { 
        return sortedList.get();
    }
    public void set(ImmutableList<T> immutableList) { 

        this.property.setValue(this);

        final ImmutableList<T> oldList = this.backingList;
        final ImmutableList<T> newList = immutableList;
        listeners.forEach(l -> l.onChanged(new Change<T>(this) {
            private int changeNum = 0;
            @Override
            public boolean next() {
                changeNum++;
                return changeNum <= 2 ? true : false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean wasUpdated() {
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public void reset() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            @Override
            public int getFrom() {
                return 0;
            }
            @Override
            public int getTo() {
                return changeNum == 1 ? oldList.size() - 1 : newList.size() - 1;
            }
            @Override
            public List<T> getRemoved() {
                return changeNum == 1 ? oldList : ImmutableList.of();
            }
            @Override
            public List<T> getAddedSubList() { 
                return changeNum == 1 ? ImmutableList.of() : newList;
            }
            @Override
            protected int[] getPermutation() {
                int[] permutations = new int[changeNum == 1 ? oldList.size() : newList.size()];
                for (int i = 0; i < permutations.length; i++) { 
                    permutations[i] = i;
                }
                return permutations;
            }

        }));
        this.backingList = immutableList;

        invalidationListeners.forEach(l -> l.invalidated(this));

    }

    public ImmutableList<T> get() { 
        return backingList;
    }
    public ObjectProperty<ObservableList<T>> asProperty() { 
        return property;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return backingList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return backingList.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return backingList.contains(o);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return backingList.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        return backingList.toArray();
    }

    @Override
    public <B> B[] toArray(B[] a) {
        return backingList.toArray(a);
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public boolean add(T e) {
        return backingList.add(e);
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return backingList.remove(o);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return backingList.containsAll(c);
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c) {
        return backingList.addAll(c);
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends T> c) {
        return backingList.addAll(index, c);
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return backingList.removeAll(c);
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return backingList.retainAll(c);
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public void clear() {
        backingList.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        return backingList.get(index);
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public T set(int index, T element) {
        return backingList.set(index, element);
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public void add(int index, T element) {
        backingList.add(index, element);
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public T remove(int index) {
        return backingList.remove(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        return backingList.indexOf(o);
    }

    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
        return backingList.lastIndexOf(o);
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<T> listIterator() {
        return backingList.listIterator();
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<T> listIterator(int index) {
        return backingList.listIterator(index);
    }

    @Override
    public ImmutableList<T> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        return backingList.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public void addListener(InvalidationListener listener) {
        invalidationListeners.add(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeListener(InvalidationListener listener) {
        invalidationListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void addListener(ListChangeListener<? super T> listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeListener(ListChangeListener<? super T> listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public boolean addAll(T... elements) {
        return backingList.addAll(ImmutableList.copyOf(elements));
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public boolean setAll(T... elements) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public boolean setAll(Collection<? extends T> col) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public boolean removeAll(T... elements) {
        return backingList.removeAll(ImmutableList.copyOf(elements));
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public boolean retainAll(T... elements) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public void remove(int from, int to) {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { 
        return backingList.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: if the values can be shuffled arround then it is no longer immutable. Return the mutable version whenever you need sorting. Or sort into new object.

Comment: asSorted looks like it should work (using the returned list as the items in the tableView) - you bind the sortedList's comparator to that of the table, don't you?

Comment: Not the answer I wanted to hear. But I supposed I could utilize ListChangeListener to keep the SortedList instance in sync with the immutable data model.

Comment: Actually, I think the SortedList physically manipulates the internal backing list according to the JavaDoc. If its immutable it cannot do that.

Comment: no, the sortedList does nothing to the backing list, it just keeps a reference to the position of the items - which part of the doc makes you think it does change the backing list?

Comment: BTW (unrelated): the change - assuming it's a ListChangeListener.Change - looks fishy. How would a replace (that's swapping out the whole list) ever produce a wasUpdated?

Comment: Haha I knew somebody would call me out on the ListChangeListener. I didn't 100% feel like I did it optimally. What would you recommend?

Comment: It was the official documentation that cites sorting changes are propagated back to the list. I'll poke around and see if your statement leads me to a solution though... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/SortedList.html

Comment: it's the other way round - all changes in the backing list are propagated to the sortedList :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The part you asked about: a SortedList is just a wrapper around its backing list, it does not change it in any way. So you can wrap any list - mutable or not - into a SortedList and use that in the TableView. In the example of your previous question:

```
ObservableList<NumericCombo> immutable = 
        FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableList(values);
 //       new ImmutableObservableList<>(values);

TableView<NumericCombo> tableView = new TableView<>();
SortedList sorted = new SortedList(immutable);
tableView.setItems(sorted);
sorted.comparatorProperty().bind(tableView.comparatorProperty());
```

The part you did not ask about (how to get the notifications right).

- don't implement ObservableList from scratch, instead go from ObservableListBase
- when swapping out the backing list, call the support methods provided by super to notify the listeners

A simple example:

```
public class ImmutableObservableList<E> extends ObservableListBase<E> {

    private List<E> backing;

    public ImmutableObservableList(List<E> backingList) {
        this.backing = backingList;
    }

    public void setBackingList(List<E> backingList) {
        beginChange();
        if (this.backing != null) {
            nextRemove(0, this.backing);
        }
        this.backing = backingList;
        if (backingList != null) {
            nextAdd(0, backingList.size());
        }
        endChange();
    }
    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        if (backing == null) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        return backing.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return backing != null ? backing.size() : 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks! I had to read it a few times but I think   `FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableList()` makes sense now and somewhat already does what I am trying to do. And thanks for pointing out the proper swap operation. I'll go ahead and commit these changes.

Comment: I suppose  better semantic for this class would be a `SwappableList` rather than an `ImmutableObservableList`, since it is not necessary immutable with the swap operation.

Comment: good point - but didn't bother to find a better name, just took yours (more or less :-)

Comment: I implemented this, and everything now works great! Thanks for your help kelopatra.